# "Unnest" Overlapping Time Intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, lubridate

I am trying to create plots for a set of filters that operate in a lead/lag fashion.

*A short description on lead/lag:*

*When a new filter is put online, it is put in the lag position meaning water passes through it after it passes through the primary (aka lead) filter. When the lead filter is clogged, the current lag filter is moved into the lead position. To summarize, a filter starts in the lag position then is bumped into the lead position.*

*Visually, you can imagine it like this:*

[image: Filter Diagram]

What I need to do is "unnest" (for lack of a better word) the periods of time where there is overlap. In other words, I would like each filter to have a consecutive run of timestamps, regardless of the lead/lag position it is in.

The structure of the data is as follows:

```
data <- structure(list(record_timestamp = structure(c(1608192000, 1608192060, 1608192120, 1608192180, 1608192240, 1608192300, 1608192360, 1608192420, 1608192480, 1608192540, 1608192600, 1608192660, 1608192720, 1608192780, 1608192840, 1608192900, 1608192960, 1608193020, 1608193080, 1608193140, 1608193200, 1608193260, 1608193320, 1608193380, 1608193440, 1608193500, 1608193560, 1608193620, 1608193680, 1608193740, 1608193800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), flow = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), lag_start = structure(c(1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), lead_start = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), changeout_interval = new("Interval",     .Data = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 660, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), start = structure(c(1608192000,     1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000,     1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000,     1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660,     1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660,     1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260,     1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), spec = structure(list(    cols = list(record_timestamp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",     "collector")), flow = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",     "collector")), polish_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",     "collector")), lead_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",     "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",     "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

What I'm envisioning for the end result the data would look like:

```
end_data <- structure(list(record_timestamp = structure(c(1608192000, 1608192060,1608192120, 1608192180, 1608192240, 1608192300, 1608192360, 1608192420,1608192480, 1608192540, 1608192600, 1608192660, 1608192720, 1608192780,1608192840, 1608192900, 1608192960, 1608193020, 1608193080, 1608193140,1608193200, 1608192660, 1608192720, 1608192780, 1608192840, 1608192900,1608192960, 1608193020, 1608193080, 1608193140, 1608193200, 1608193260,1608193320, 1608193380, 1608193440, 1608193500, 1608193560,1608193620,1608193680, 1608193740, 1608193800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), flow = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), lag_start = structure(c(1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000,1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000,1608192000,1608192000, 1608192000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660,1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), lead_start = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660,1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660,1608192660, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1608193260,1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260,1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260), class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), filter_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = c("spec_tbl_df",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -41L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(record_timestamp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character","collector")), flow = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double","collector")), polish_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character","collector")), lead_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), filter_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double","collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess","collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

This would double up timestamps, but it would allow easier plotting because I can `group_by` on the filter_id column.

What I have so far is a set of time intervals for each filter, from start to finish, lead through lag. Here's that code:

```
intervals <-  data %>% 
  distinct(lag_start, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(changeout_interval = interval(lag_start, lead(lag_start, 2))) %>%
  select(record_timestamp, changeout_interval)
```

From there, how can I filter all the timestamps that fall within each of those intervals? Almost like a conditional `pivot_longer`.

The ultimate goal is to be able to plot the full life of a filter, both lead and lag, with just a few lines of `ggplot2`. Here is what I envision for the plot:

```
grouped_data <- data %>%
  group_by(lag_start) %>%
  mutate(elapsed_time = difftime(record_timestamp,
                                  record_timestamp[1],
                                  units = "mins"),
         total_flow = cumsum(flow))

ggplot(grouped_data, aes(x = elapsed_time, y = total_flow)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = as.factor(lag_start)))
```

But this plot does not include the flow for each filter when it is changed into the lead position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dense_rank` to group the filters by `lag_start` and then create one record per filter. This leaves the information in wide format as `interval` and `end_data` had different data structures.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  select(-changeout_interval) %>% # example only as interval appeared to calculate this
  mutate(filter_id = dense_rank(lag_start)) %>%
  group_by(filter_id) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(lead_start = lead(lead_start), lead_end = lead(lead_start), changeout_interval = interval(lag_start, lead_end))

# A tibble: 3 x 7
  record_timestamp     flow lag_start           lead_start          filter_id lead_end           
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>                  <int> <dttm>             
1 2020-12-17 08:00:00    20 2020-12-17 08:00:00 2020-12-17 08:11:00         1 2020-12-17 08:21:00
2 2020-12-17 08:11:00    15 2020-12-17 08:11:00 2020-12-17 08:21:00         2 NA                 
3 2020-12-17 08:21:00    10 2020-12-17 08:21:00 NA                          3 NA
```

Updated in response to clarifying additions to question. Uses same approach of `dense_rank` and then switches to long format via `pivot_longer` to make the `cumsum` requirement easier to plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- data %>%
  select(-changeout_interval) %>% # example only as interval appeared to calculate this
  mutate(filter_lag = dense_rank(lag_start),
         filter_lead = filter_lag - 1) %>%
  select(-lag_start, -lead_start) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("filter_"),
               names_to = "position",
               names_prefix = "filter_",
               values_to = "filter") %>%
  filter(filter > 0) %>% # drops the starting filter as data shows no lead filter?
  group_by(filter) %>%
  mutate(elapsed_time = difftime(record_timestamp, record_timestamp[1], units = "mins"),
         rolling_flow = cumsum(flow))
```

Plotting the `elapsed_time` and `rolling_flow`

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = as.numeric(elapsed_time),
                      y = rolling_flow,
                      color = factor(filter))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I've added to the question to help clarify. I am looking to expand the data to make plotting easier

Comment: @setty updated answer to generate plot with cumulative flow for both lag and lead

Comment: Brilliant! That is exactly what I was after. Thanks for responding to the updates!